# how to upgrade my Ubuntu Studio 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.1?

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-studio

how to upgrade my Ubuntu Studio 14.04 to Ubuntu 14.1 or 14.04 without affecting the data and personal files?

Comment: Why would you want to upgrade a LTS release that's supported for years to a development release that's supported for months?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Update Manager, from the Systems menu. 
Above the packages list will be a notification to upgrade to the latest version - Press this button to upgrade.
It Updates Upgrades (if chosen), I have newer seen it to mess with my personal files or data, only the installed packages.

You can also use the terminal with these commands:

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`
- `sudo do-release-upgrade`

It request your password, but doesn't show anything (security)
And it will ask for confirmation on upgrades.